# How to compress static files using the Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to compress static files when self-hosting using OWIN?

I’m able to compress WebAPI responses using the library Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression with the following code:

```
HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfiguration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
```

However, I can’t find a way to insert a message handler into the StaticFiles provider pipeline.

Current code… (app is defined as IAppBuilder app and webPath is a local path).

```
FileServerOptions clientOptions = new FileServerOptions()
{
    RequestPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString(""),
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(webPath),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
};
app.UseFileServer(clientOptions);
```

Comment: See this: https://github.com/Thorium/Owin.Compression